# How to provide a network address to a DSL connection in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, broadband, dsl

I'm a new Ubuntu user(Desktop OS). As I've switched from Windows 10  to Ubuntu 12.4 just before few days. I'm unable to set up a DSL connection in Ubuntu as I can't find any option to provide a network address.
In Windows 10 I used to provide it through following process:
Run>ncpa.cpl>right click on Ethernet>properties>configure>advanced>network address>value
(The value looks something like 333344445555)>OK
Then I used to set up a new dial-up connection (Broadband PPPoE) through network and sharing centre. And then provide a username and password.
So, can anyone please help me to provide a network address in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

first connect your lan cable and then from up panel in ubuntu louncher search network connection after choose it you can see ubuntu network manager for setup local network with specific ip address click add and choose lan or etherenet then choose ipv4setting tab and in method menu choose manual after click add and specif your ip address last of do setting save 
after for create adsl (ppoe) connection again click on add in network manager and choose DSL and put your username and password and then save it in ppp setting tab you can edite autonthication of security profile

Comment: Dear I just need to provide a network address. Because when I provide username, service and password, then new "DSL authentication" window pops out. So, Where could I get the option to type the network address?

Comment: Note: In windows if I provide username and password without network address then it shows "Error 691" I.e. authentication failure. So I need to provide network address. And in Ubuntu 12.4 I can't find any option to provide network address.

Comment: click on add in network manager and choose DSL and choose ipv4setting tab and in method choose manually and add network address

Comment: Doesn't work. Here I can't get any option to put n/w address. In manual I get option to put address, netmask and gateway. And in each field we need to put an IP address which looks like AAA.BBB.CCC.QQQ but I need to put a network address which is like aaaabbbbcccc In network address there are no Colon's or semicolons

Comment: ok understand you must open terminal with ctrl+t  first run sudo pppoeconf and then gedit /etc/ppp/chap-secrets and setup your connection , for start connect to this run pon dsl-provider and for disconnect pof dsl-provider in this config file you can put address for your ppoe connection

Comment: i find this guid for more information can use this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MAC address on Ubuntu is simple. [On this site](http://www.howtogeek.com/192173/how-and-why-to-change-your-mac-address-on-windows-linux-and-mac/) is a nice explanation how to do it.

You can change your MAC address using Network Manager and typing the new MAC address into **Cloned MAC address** field.

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively you can do it directly in terminal. So first open the terminal and run `ifconfig` (this is like `ipconfig` on Windows). It will display all your network interfaces. Then decide which interface should be changed (let's assume its `eth0`) and type:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

And again using `ifconfig` you can check you new address:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr
```

Also using Network Manager you can easily create you PPPoE connection. Depending on the version of the Network Manager you can ether [go to the DSL tab and click on Add](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx-G-Sn6IhY), or like shown in the screenshot below, first click on Add and then choose the connection type DSL. After this a dialog will appear, type you username and password, give the name to your connection and have fun.

[image]

Comment: Dear, I don't want to change MAC address just provide a network address.

Comment: what do you mean by network address then?  )))

Comment: It is a 12 digit value. In windows if we get error 691 while setting up dial up connection then we need to provide a network address value. See the main question I've given steps to provide network address in windows. And as I'm a new Ubuntu user I don't know much about it. Can u pls just provide me steps to give a network address?

Comment: network address = mac address

Comment: But my n/w address and MAC address are different. I can send u screenshots. And my n/w address doesn't contain any punctuation marks. Just few No's

Comment: I need to give n/w address due to authentication failure. That is my net username address.